# Minikube doesn't start on Windows Server 2019

Tags: windows, docker, kubernetes, minikube, hyper-v

I've installed Minikube to use along with Docker on Windows Server 2019. However, when I try to start with `minikube start`, it shows the follow errors:

> Failed to start hyperv VM. Running "minikube delete" may fix it: Error loading existing host. 
> Hyper-V\Start-VM minikube
>
> ```
>     CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Start-VM], VirtualizationException
>     FullyQualifiedErrorId : OperationFailed,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.StartVM
> ```

`minikube delete` does not fix it.

When I start with `minikube start --driver=hyper-v`, it shows:

> Exiting due to DRV_UNSUPPORTED_OS: The driver 'hyper-v' is not supported on windows/amd64

I already made an external switch on HyperV, as suggested in some videos, but it also did not work.

**How can I fix it?**

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled hyper-v?
On sv2019 you can practice k8s by enabling it on docker desktop, it's much easier and simpler.

[image]

Comment: and, docker-desktop is supported on windows server 2019 ?